# Does a maximal ideal in a unital commutative ring contain the set of zero-divisors?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Intuitively I think that since $R/M$ will be a field and can't have zero divisors, the set of zero-divisors must lie inside $M$ that they vanish in $R/M$.

I tried to prove this, but I got stuck, so I'm afraid that my intuition is wrong.

Is this a correct statement? If not, does it hold when $R$ is a finite unital commutative ring?

Comment: Is the implication $"M\subseteq R$ maximal $\Rightarrow$ $R/M$ field" even true if $R$ has zero divisors?

Comment: @mathmax: Yes. Ideal correspondence theorem still holds and the proof of the implication remains just the same I think.

Comment: @mathmax All we need for that is $R$ commutative with $1$.

Comment: I thought we needed to have an integral domain somewhere in the proof, but now I've checked that we don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the field of two elements $F_2$, the ring $F_2\times F_2$ contains the maximal ideal $F_2\times \{0\}$. Does this ideal contain all zero divisors?

Comment: I sure do get a lot of mileage out of this example...

Comment: Can we say that in a finite ring any maximal ideal is a subset of zero divisors? Because any element is either a unit or a zero divisor. I'm talking about a unital commutative ring.

Comment: @math.n00b You can do better than that: in any commutative Artinian ring, the elements of maximal ideals are zero divisors.

Comment: Interesting. Why is it so? Is it true that in any commutative Artinian ring all elements are either units or zero-diviors? If yes, why?

Comment: @math.n00b Let $x$ be any element of a commutative Artinian ring $R$. Then the chain $xR\supseteq x^2R\supseteq\ldots$ stabilizes. This means there is an $n$ and an $r$ such that $x^n=x^{n+1}r$. Rearranging you get $x^n(1-rx)=0$. Suppose $x$ isn't a zero divisor. Then you can cancel the $x^n$ from the left to conclude $1-rx=0$, whence $x$ is a unit. Thus the elements that aren't zero divisors are units.